# Serializing immutable collections with protobuf-net

Tags: c#, .net, immutability, protobuf-net

I'm trying to serialize a class with protobuf-net which contains an immutable collection as a member.

The collection type, `ImmutableList<T>`, implements `ICollection<T>` but returns `true` for the `IsReadOnly` property. So any attempts to modify it throw an exception.

Protobuf-net seems to rely on being able to call `Add(T)` after creating a collection in order to populate it. This obviously won't work with an immutable collection, which is a shame because protobuf-net works beautifully with all my other data types, which are also immutable.

So my question is, what options do I have to be able to serialize such collections?

---

The code for `ImmutableList<T>` is listed below:

```
public sealed class ImmutableList<T> : IList<T>, IList
{
    private readonly T[] m_Items;

    public ImmutableList(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        m_Items = source.ToArray();
    }

    public T[] ToArray()
    {
        T[] newArray = new T[m_Items.Length];
        m_Items.CopyTo(newArray, 0);
        return newArray;
    }

    private static void ThrowNotSupported()
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("The attempted operation was not supported as the collection is read-only.");
    }

    #region IList<T> Members

    int IList.Add(object value)
    {
        ThrowNotSupported();
        return -1;
    }

    void IList.Clear()
    {
        ThrowNotSupported();
    }

    void IList<T>.Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        ThrowNotSupported();
    }

    void IList.Insert(int index, object value)
    {
        ThrowNotSupported();
    }

    void IList.Remove(object value)
    {
        ThrowNotSupported();
    }

    void IList.RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        ThrowNotSupported();
    }

    void IList<T>.RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        ThrowNotSupported();
    }

    T IList<T>.this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Items[index];
        }
        set
        {
            ThrowNotSupported();
        }
    }

    object IList.this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Items[index];
        }
        set
        {
            ThrowNotSupported();
        }
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Items[index];
        }
    }

    bool IList.Contains(object value)
    {
        return Array.IndexOf(m_Items, value) != -1;
    }

    int IList.IndexOf(object value)
    {
        return Array.IndexOf(m_Items, value);
    }

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return Array.IndexOf(m_Items, item);
    }

    bool IList.IsFixedSize
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICollection<T> Members

    void ICollection<T>.Add(T item)
    {
        ThrowNotSupported();
    }

    void ICollection<T>.Clear()
    {
        ThrowNotSupported();
    }

    bool ICollection<T>.Remove(T item)
    {
        ThrowNotSupported();
        return false;
    }

    object ICollection.SyncRoot
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Items;
        }
    }

    bool ICollection.IsSynchronized
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return IndexOf(item) != -1;
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        m_Items.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int index)
    {
        m_Items.CopyTo(array, index);
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Items.Length;
        }
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region IEnumerable<T> Members

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<T>)m_Items).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return m_Items.GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: **Marc Gravell:** Do you have any ideas on how you might be able to handle this out of the box? I don't mind helping with the implementation if you know how you'd like it to be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment there is no support for that; but it seems a reasonable scenario. It depends on what you mean (comments) by "out of the box"; if you mean "today, without code changed", it would need to use a surrogate against the DTO, or a shim property that exposed the immutable list as a mutable one; if you mean "moving forwards", I suspect we could look at list-constructors that take (perferable) `IEnumerable[<T>]` or (less preferable, but doable) `T[]`, and simply construct the list after buffering the data.

Comment: Thanks, you answered both my questions. The comment was directed at moving forwards, the original question was aimed at today.

Comment: With regard to moving forwards, is this something you'd accept a patch for?

Comment: @JacobStanley sure, if it worked, had some level of tests, and didn't break the existing code. But: note that protobuf-net does a lot of meta-programming, so unless you're pretty familiar with `ILGenerator`, you might want to wait for me to have a look at it

Comment: I've played with ILGenerator for a few simple things, like a high performance Activator.CreateInstance implementation. I'll have a look when I get back to work and see what I'm in for. So your preferred method would be to buffer the data in to some intermediate list during deserialization then pass it to the immutable collection constructor once complete?

Comment: @JacobStanley yep; to be honest I can probably have a look pretty quickly - just I've been travelling all this week